# python code of geograpy module gives some error

Tags: python-3.x

solve some error of nltk, but these are remaining

```
import geograpy
url = 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-26919928'
places = geograpy.get_place_context(url=url)
```

this is generated errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Monika\Desktop\p.py", line 3, in <module>
    places = geograpy.get_place_context(url=url)
  File "C:\Users\Monika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\geograpy\__init__.py", line 11, in get_place_context
    pc.set_cities()
  File "C:\Users\Monika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\geograpy\places.py", line 137, in set_cities
    self.populate_db()
  File "C:\Users\Monika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\geograpy\places.py", line 30, in populate_db
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Users\Monika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 274: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Your're going to have to place some of your code where you are getting the errors.

Comment: in the site-packages?

Comment: From what i'm seeing its line 3 of p.py on your desktop that is throwing these errors

Comment: the remark about `nltk` doesn't land... please elaborate and put it in context. Fix question tag if `nltk` is related to question.

Comment: its show some missing nltk data like punkt , word etc. i solved it by  nltk.download() method. so that error is already solved.